# Setting Image in code behind is not showing up in wpf datagrid column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a data template to show icon in a datagrid column. I set the image source in code behind. But somehow the image is not showing up in the grid at runtime. Am I missing anything??

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="iconTemplate">          
  <Image/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code behind

```
var cellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["iconTemplate"];
var image = cellTemplate.LoadContent() as Image;

image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\images\16x16\image.png"));
column.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
```

Setting datagrid template column's cell template in xaml.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comments" CellTemplate="{StaticResource iconTemplate}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I think this is because of StaticResource... StaticResource  are freezable objects.. all statics resources are resolved at load or initializing and changes made at runtime will not show any effect... try to do the same with DynamicResources...

Comment: somehow setting DynamicResource is not working too

Answer (score 1):

[`LoadContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent.aspx) is not going to help here:

> Loads the content of the template as an instance of an object and returns the root element of the content.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Windows.DependencyObject 
> The root element of the content. Calling this multiple times returns separate instances.

Further you cannot modify DataTemplates as they are being sealed once they are used. You could reference the DataTemplate as a DynamicResource, and replace the old template completely at runtime.